# Autofill a number sequence from column A to column B

Tags: vba, excel

It is a follow up question from this:

[Autofill the same number from column A in column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494340/autofill-the-same-number-from-column-a-in-column-b/38494614#38494614)

I would like to create output like the following:

```
  Column A | Column B
1.    1          1
2.               2
3.    2          1
4.               2
5.               3
```

I tried brettdj's answer with some modifications in FormulaR1C1 and now formula followed is.

```
=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",RC[-1],R[-1]C+1)
```

But it starts counting from the column A number rather than 1.

How to make it start counting from 1?

Comment: Good on you to open a new question rather than berating the answerers of the previous question.  Glad to have a user like you in SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the formula `"=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",RC[-1],R[-1]C+1)"` with this:

`"=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",1,R[-1]C+1)"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
=IF(ROW(A1)=1,1,IF(A1<>"",1,OFFSET(B1,-1,0)+1))
```

Which requires a test for the first row and then uses the `OFFSET` function for subsequent rows.

E.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, below is the answer for you.

Assuming your data starts with A2 then Apply the below formula in B2 and drag down up to the last

```
=IF(AND(A2<>"",B1<>""),1,B1+1)
```

**Proof**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**edit**: my first answer was to obtain the sequence as requested in your [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494340/autofill-the-same-number-from-column-a-in-column-b/38494614#38494614)

so I edited to add code for your actual question...

---

code for actual question

I'd go like follows

```
Sub FastUpdate(rng As Range)
    With rng.Offset(, 1)
        .Cells(1, 1) = 1
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC1),R[-1]C+1,1)"
    End With
End Sub
```

to be used like follows

```
Sub main()

    FastUpdate Worksheets("MySheetName").Range("A1:A14") '<--| use whatever range you need. best use fully qualified reference

End Sub
```

---

code for linked question

I'd go like follows:

```
Sub FastUpdate(rng As Range)
    With rng.Offset(, 1)
        .Value = .Offset(, -1).Value
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

to be used like follows:

```
Sub main()

    FastUpdate Worksheets("MySheetName").Range("A1:A14") '<--| use whatever range you need. best use fully qualified reference

End Sub
```